# Makefile with headers including headers

Tags: c++, c, makefile

In `app.c`:

```
#include "app.h"
```

In `app.h`:

```
#include "model/world.h"
#include "controller/controller.h"
```

How do I write a target for `app.o` in a makefile? Should I include all three headers in the prerequisites?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should list all dependencies of app.c which might need a recompilation of app.o.

You might find g++ -MM app.c useful: -MM will list all dependencies of app.c in a make format. You can even automate it and have your makefile semi-automatically handle dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.o : app.c app.h model/world.h controller/controller.h
    gcc -c app.c
```

Yes, you need to include all three headers as dependencies. Makefiles: if anything on the right of `:` has changed, then it needs to remake the thing on the left.  If you fix a bug in your controller and cut out three arguments from one of the functions, and the app calls that function from the controller, then the app needs to be remade to deal with the change.

Otherwise when the app walks over to the controller and asks for function X with 5 arguments, the new and improved controller isn't going to know what the hell the app is talking about. Error will be thrown. Fire and blood everywhere. And it all ends in tears.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example how I solved this issue.
`gcc -MM` generates rules from the given source file's include directives. Try it on a source file containing include directives to see it's output.

```
# src/x.c src/y.c ... => build/x.o build/y.o ...
OBJ = $(patsubst src/%.c,build/%.o,$(wildcard src/*.c))

# src/x.c src/y.c ... => build/x.d build/y.d ...
#                        `-> these files will include the generated rules
INCLUDE_PREQS = $(patsubst src/%.c,build/%.d,$(wildcard src/*.c))

all: main

main: $(OBJ)
    gcc -o $@ $^

## compile object from src/x.c to build/x.o
# src/x.c src/y.c ... => build/x.o build/y.o
build/%.o : src/%.c
    gcc -o $@ -c $<

## generate header prerequisite rules
# -MT $(patsubst build/%.d,build/%.o,$@)
#   `-> set the generated target to be build/%.o
build/%.d: src/%.c
    gcc -MM -MT $(patsubst build/%.d,build/%.o,$@) $< > $@

## include the generated rules
include $(INCLUDE_PREQS)
```

Comment: You can combine compilation and dependency generation into a single command, using `-MMD -MP`...

Answer (score 0):

You should never need to manually specify header dependencies in makefiles.

Add `-MMD -MP` to compiler flags. It will make the compiler output `.d` files in addition to `.o`. Those are little makefiles specifying the dependencies. You then `-include` them into the main makefile.

Something like following:

```
SOURCES := 1.c 2.c

program: $(patsubst %,%.o,$(SOURCES))
    gcc $^ -o $@

%.c.o: %.c
    gcc -MMD -MP $< -c -o $@

-include $(patsubst %,%.d,$(SOURCES))
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
SRC     = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ     = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SRC))
DEP     = $(patsubst %.o, %.mm, $(OBJ))

include $(DEP)

app:    $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJ)

.FORCE:
%.mm:  .FORCE
    $(CC) -MM $*.c > $*.mm
```

Here: `DEP` is a list of dependency files that need to be included (ending in mm). There is a rule to build the mm files that generates the dependency for the file. You force the build of the dependencies that are then included as dependencies to check your actual dependencies

Answer (score -1):

No, you should not list the headers as dependencies!  This is redundant with the specification that already exists in the form of your `#include` directives.  And sooner or later redundancy usually causes problems, because as your project grows you will end up with inconsistent lists.

There is also a widespread though naive misconception that only header files are dependencies.  This can lead to wrong builds, because many other reasons like changed command line switches, a changed compiler or changed hardware architecture, get overseen.

The solution to both problems is to use a reliable build tool: [makepp](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/) handles these cases and can even scan for sub includes in include files that weren't even built yet, when you started it.

*There is much more to makepp.  Besides doing almost all that GNU make can, there are lots more useful things, and you can even extend your makefiles with some Perl programming.*

Comment: For a simple program, automatic dependency generation is overkill. Naming dependencies you care about (e.g. the one or two header files you might modify) is enough.

Comment: On the other hand, the example here suggests a program built from files in multiple directories, with headers including other headers. Maintaining dependencies this complex by hand is painful and error prone.